# Prove that if $ab=1$ then $a=b$, $\forall a,b \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how could I prove for integers $a\neq b$ then $ab \neq 1$.

Attempt.Proof by contrapositive. Assume $ab=1$ Then the only cases are $(1)(1)=1$ and $(-1)(-1)=1$ Thus $a=b$ I have a feeling this is not right. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you think that $1$ has integer factors other than $\pm1$?

Comment: For $a,b \in \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: for a,b $\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Is there any way I should use the division algorithm to approach this? I was thinking a proof by contradiction but could make no progress

Comment: @lordsharktheunknown So should I say since the only integer factors are $1$ and $-1$ thus $(1)(1)=(-1)(-1)=1$ so $a=b$?

Comment: That is a correct way to go, but you must explain why you think $1,-1$ are the only integer factors of $1$.  Why can't $n*m = 1$ where *neither* $n$ nor $m = 1$.

Comment: If $ab=1$ then $a\ne 0\ne b$, so $|a|,|b|\in \Bbb N.$ And  $|ab|$ is $the$ positive member of $\{ab,-(ab)\}$ while $|a|\cdot |b|$ is $some$ positive member of $\{ab, a(-b),(-a)b, (-a)(-b)\}=\{ab,-(ab)\},$ so $|a|\cdot |b|=|ab|=1$.... Show that if $x,y \in \Bbb N$ and $xy=1$ then $x=y=1.$ Apply this with $x=|a|$ and $y=|b|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $ab=1$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since $1$ is the multiplicative identity of $\mathbb{Z}$, we find that $a=b^{-1}$. If $a=1$, then $b=1$ as well. If $a=-1$, then we also have that $b=-1$. What are the multiplicative inverses of other elements of $\mathbb{Z}$? Particularly, are they integers? Conclude that $ab=1$ implies that $a=b=\pm1$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

As $ab=1$, we can say $a$ divides $1$ because there is $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such as $ab=1$. So $a$ can be $1$ or $-1$. In the case $a=1$ we'll have that $b=1$. And if $a = -1$ we'll have that $b=-1$. And these are the only options.